# Why changing image format changes the area shown on the LCD screen?

Tags: canon, pixels

Recording pixels option when set to **Large 14M 4320x3240**, in **Canon PowerShot SX 210 IS**, puts black bars on the vertical sides of the screen. The shot is NOT thus fully seen in its LCD screen.

Why is this happening? Is this normal?

Comment: and how about mentioning the reasons for down vote?

Comment: The question is fine for me, maybe you could try a more descriptive name so that it will be easier for other people with the same doubt to find it?

Comment: @Francesco I was about to post the whole problem in the title, but then I'd have to paste the same thing again in the body too..that's why. And secondly, you could have bothered to modify the title yourself to make it more descriptive?

Comment: @anisha I don't have great editing powers, so it was easier to suggest you to do it.

Comment: @Francesco Alright then suggest the better title and I'll edit this one.

Comment: I have proposed an edit if the mods think it's fine you'll see it live, otherwise it means that it was not so good :-)

Comment: @Francesco what is the way to talk to mods here? I mean how did you do that?

Comment: @Francesco That is indeed a good title now :)

Comment: @Anisha if you have gained enough points you can edit the post of another user. This edit is only a proposal that the mods will then check and maybe commit.

Comment: It's not just mods — anyone with enough reputation can approve an edit. That means no one will get overwhelmed, so edit away without fear of annoying anyone. (And you get a small rep gain when your edits are accepted.) Once you hit 3000, you can make edits directly with no need for approval.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The LCD screen on your camera is a 16:9 aspect ratio, so when you shoot in a 4:3 aspect ratio, it puts black bars in the 'extra' space.

Aspect ratio is just the ratio of the height and the width of your image.  Your LCD is a 'widescreen' LCD with a fairly common ratio of 16:9, however, most digital pictures are shot at 4:3.  When you change your camera to this format (4:3), the camera does its best to fit as much of the picture in your LCD without cutting anything off.  What this means is that the center 2.5" of your 3" is really only used on most '*normal* ' pictures, the rest shows black bars.

Comment: @Anisha Kaul - No problem.

Comment: and shooting on a 4:3 aspect ratio is better than 16:9, in terms of quality?

Comment: Your sensor is probably 4:3, so to make the image 16:9, the camera throws away a strip at the top and bottom.

Comment: Thanks @Evan , does aspect ratio has to do anything with the quality?

Comment: @Anisha Aspect ratio doesn't directly influence picture quality (you *can* take a high quality panorama, *as well as* a high quality panorama). You can lose picture quality by not maintaining aspect ratio when resizing/scaling an image, which is why you *should* crop an image to change the aspect ratio (which is how your camera behaves when shooting in a non-native aspect ratio)

Comment: @Rowland Thanks, this means if I have to resize the image, only then I should shoot in 4:3 aspect ration, otherwise I am fine with 16:9 wide?

Comment: @Anisha I mean that if you've got a 4:3 image, and you wish to resize/scale, you should have a output image that is also in 4:3 ratio; if you want an output ratio different to that, you crop, rather than resize

Comment: See [What are the advantages of shooting a particular aspect ratio?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/826/what-are-the-advantages-of-shooting-a-particular-aspect-ratio)