# What do these differences mean between the Canon 700D and Nikon 5300D?

Tags: dslr, digital

I am buying a camera to satisfy my photography hunger while travelling (+ Wild) and for family photography.

I am planning to buy a Canon 700D but am really confused when comparing it with the Nikon D5300 ([Comparison Here](http://www.dpreview.com/products/compare/side-by-side?products=canon_eos700d&products=nikon_d5300)).

I want to know about following points and how they play an important role in my choice:

1. Autofocus points - 9 Vs 39
2. Color filter array RGB Color Filter Array vs Primary color filter
3. Image ISO - None vs Auto, 100 - 12800 (25600 with boost)
4. Image Ratio- [1:1, 4:3, 3:2, 16:9] vs 3:2
5. Effective Pixels - 18 Vs 24

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In reality these cameras are much more similar than they are different. They are both basically one step up from entry level DSLRs in both Nikon and Canon's lineup, and they are both about a generation old.

I would argue that the differences you point out realistically matter very little, but yes on paper they may seem to be substantial.

Specifically going down the line:

1. More autofocus points is typically a good thing, but you have to keep in mind the sensitivity of the points in question as well as the lenses you are using and the subject you are shooting. More information here: [What is the advantage of the huge number of AF points?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22627/what-is-the-advantage-of-the-huge-number-of-af-points)
2. I'm not sure that there is any true difference here, it could just be terminology used in Nikon vs Canon.
3. DPReview is sometimes missing specs for cameras. The Canon 700D(T5i) has ISO sensitivity from 100-12,800 and expansion up to 25,600. In a pure spec sheet comparison they are identical, but of course that isn't the end of the story. More information here: [What is "ISO" on a digital camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6615/what-is-iso-on-a-digital-camera)
4. This comes down to what limiting settings you want to make within the camera vs having the option to achieve via post processing. It is generally advised to shoot the image in the largest ratio(i.e native ratio) of your camera and crop in post if desired. Because of this I would call this a non-issue or difference that doesn't matter to the vast majority of users. More information: [What are the advantages of shooting a particular aspect ratio?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/826/what-are-the-advantages-of-shooting-a-particular-aspect-ratio)
5. This is what I would call a hotly debated topic, but I would say that yes more megapixels in the D5300 is a good thing so it is a slight advantage. If you plan to blow up images very large or do a lot of post capture cropping, this can be handy. More information: [Do megapixels matter with modern sensor technology?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14773/do-megapixels-matter-with-modern-sensor-technology)